# tensorflow train a model with gpus and inference with java api

Tags: spring, tensorflow, spring-cloud-dataflow

I've trained a model in tensorflow with 4 GPUs. I would use it to make inference with tensorflow Java API (in spring cloud dataflow), but I get this error:

> org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot assign a
>   device to node 'embedding/embedding_matrix/read': Could not satisfy
>   explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no devices
>   matching that specification are registered in this process; available
>   devices: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0

I can't understand this problem. Is it not possible to use a model trained with GPU in an "standard" environment?

Comment: Can you show us the code that's loading the trained model, and (if possible) the code that's exporting the trained model?